# adding a variable to an entity - featuretools

Tags: python, featuretools

I'm trying to add a new variable to an entity.

I'm trying to add a variable as follows:

```
es['Product'].add_variable("inventory", data=inventory_series)
```

however I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

and if I specify the type argument as an int,

```
es['Product'].add_variable("inventory", data=inventory_series)
```

I get a different error:

```
--> 558         new_v = type(new_id, entity=self)
    559         self.variables.append(new_v)
    560 

TypeError: 'entity' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

is there another way to add a new variable to an Entity?

Thank you,

Comment: one question - any reason you can't add this variable to the original dataframe when you create the entity? I ask because this method is planned to be removed in the next release of featuretools to encourage users to do the data prep before creating an entity set.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify type of data in `add_variable`. I guess you've tried this way:

```
es['Product'].add_variable('inventory', data=inventory_series, type=int)
```

and got this error:

> TypeError: 'entity' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

But the type must be one from [`featuretools.variable_types`](https://docs.featuretools.com/api_reference.html#variable-types). Like this:

```
es['Product'].add_variable(
    'inventory',
    data=inventory_series,
    type=ft.variable_types.Ordinal
)
```